# Can settlers/builders be captured at sea?

Tags: civilization-6

Is it possible to capture settlers, builders etc when they're embarked, or will they be killed?

[image: Embarked Enemy Settler]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can capture them just the same as with land units, see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Currently I can't capture a settler at sea. The settler is in shallow water and so is my horse archer. I'm at war with the civ and captured one of their settlers on land a few turns before.

Answer (score 2):

You can not capture or even pass through a worker or settler at sea if your unit is an embarked unit. Maybe you can if you have the amphibious promotion but I havent tried. You can only do it with an actual naval unit. Frustrating when your scout is blocked by an embarked barbarian settler in a narrow straight and you can't pass by, let alone capture it.

Comment: I think you cannot do it if there's a great admiral or maybe any support unit with your naval unit! I know that I tried once before, and the barbarian builder just disappeared. Today, same thing, but *I think* it was with a sub linked to a great admiral. Maybe I had the admiral selected, not sure. I just re-loaded and succeeded this time with an un-escorted missle cruiser.

Comment: I've just captured a worker on builder with an embarked crossbowman. You need to have Shipbuilding and you cannot be in formation with civil units (there would be no room for the builder).